System proxy appears not apply for terminal and chorme
I'm getting start with mitmproxy and I'm having some issues setting a system proxy.

I start mitmproxy in a terminal

I can curl --proxy http://localhost:8080 https://example.com and see the request appear

I set the http and https proxy in the system proxies settings:


I've used Firefox retrieve the root CA certificate and have trusted it, and I can requests made by Firefox appearing in the mitmproxy log.

Requests made in chrome do not appear

Curl requests made without the --proxy option do not appear

In terminal, if I first run


export http_proxy="http:/127.0.0.1:8080"
export https_proxy="http:/127.0.0.1:8080"

Then the curl requests will appear.
Does the system proxy simply not apply to terminal and chrome?

No, the curl binary is not respecting the system setting, it reads the environment variables described in the manual page. Are you just asking a yes / no  question? If so I can answer. Same with chrome, it has its own method. Neither check the macOS settings or [use Apple’s API] - see Getting the proxy settings for a URL.
